# Zend Framework - Doctrine2 - Store EntityManager As Global Variable?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm building my first Zend/Doctrine project and would like to be able to access my Doctrine2 Entity Manager in my controllers using something like:

```
$this->em->persist($item);
```

Is there a way to do this, or should I put it in the Zend_Registry when Doctrine is bootstrap'd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, it depends upon precisely how you bootstrap Doctrine. The upshot is to get the EntityManager stored as a resource in your Bootstrap and then retrieve it in your controller.

For example, if you have method `Bootstrap::_initDoctrine()` in which you instantiate an entity manager, then returning this instance will store it in the bootstrap as a resource under the key `'doctrine'`.  Then, in your controller's `init()` method, you could have:

```
$this->em = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('doctrine');
```

Alternatively, if you use the [Bisna application resource plugin for Doctrine](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2), then you have to push down one more level to get the entity manager:

```
$this->em = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
```

Comment: I had a DoctrineEntityManager Resource that initialised the Doctrine Framework and created an instance of the EntityManager. Howver, I also want to use the ZFDebug tool with Doctrine, so I've had to use Bootstrap.php to initialise both Doctrine and ZFDebug, as ZFDebug as a Plugin or a Bootstrap initialised feature, needs an instance of the EntityManager - something that's not possible unless Doctrine is initialised 1st. Matthew Weier O'Phinney wrote an Action Helper http://mwop.net/blog/235-A-Simple-Resource-Injector-for-ZF-Action-Controllers that allows for $this->em to be used in an action